# Which word is correct 秒 or 妙

Tags: meaning-in-context

This text is talking about a man who adored a film star for a long time when he was a young man. Ten years later he met her and was not impressed.

I find for 美妙：beautiful; marvellous; nice; splendid; wonderful. I don't find this word as a noun.
I am tempted to write 'splenditity', except that word does not exist! 'splendidness' also sounds awkward. I don't like 'beauty', because '向往给你带来的' 就是 'beautiful feelings' or 'beautiful moments' rather than actual beauty, in my opinion. You won't be more beautiful because you dream about a film star.

In 1. I thought 'He means '美妙的感觉

In 2. he refers to 这美妙 with 它, which very clearly makes it a noun.

1. 天下许多事，你都可以尽性地去向往，向往给你带来的无穷美妙其实已经足够了。

Later it says:

2. 这美妙，就是在于它不真实的一面，一旦实现，便要大打折扣。

Do you think this may be a typo for 秒？ Then I could translate 美秒 as 'beautiful seconds' = 'beautiful moments' and '这美秒' as 'these beautiful moments'.

Comment: No; `美秒` is just plain wrong.

Comment: Not a good texts, not worth to digg in.

Comment: You could use 美妙 as an attributive: 美妙的时刻 = beautiful moments. Or 美妙的一瞬，美妙的瞬间，瞬间的美妙，...

Comment: Stop the insanity! There's no such thing as 美秒. For " a wonderful moment" just use 一个美丽的时刻

Answer (score 1):

「美秒」is not a word. It also doesn't make any sense.

In this context, 美妙 means "awesomeness", "wonderfulness". Noun or adjective isn't that important in Chinese as long as it makes sense.

> 天下許多事，你都可以盡性地去嚮往，嚮往給你帶來的無窮美妙其實已經足夠了。

"There are a lot of things that you can long for in this world. The unlimited wonderfulness you get when dreaming about it is actually already enough. "

> 這美妙，就是在於它不真實的一面，一旦實現，便要大打折扣。

"This wonderfulness comes from the fact that it is not real. Once you reached the goal of having the things you longed for, that feeling will get discounted (will no longer be this wonderful)."

These sentences sound like they are from a novel. The full text I found

> 人生在世，有許多解不開的結，也有許多莫須有的煩惱。因為天下許多事情，你都可以盡情地去嚮往，嚮往給你帶來的無窮美妙，其實已經足夠了。不要為嚮往的沒有實現而遺憾，實現了也許更遺憾！
>
> 人世間有許多事情，只有一直嚮往著才是最美好的。這美妙就是在於他有不真實的一面，一旦實現便要大打折扣。如果真的讓他實現了，最好只有一天，一夜，一會兒，或是短短的一瞬間，真的不能再長了。

have some deep meaning. Feels like it's something that young girls like to read in a coffee shop. It's basically saying you don't need to reach your goal to be happy. The journey is often more enjoyable than the short moment of you reaching the goal.

---

PS: Some people are saying this is not a good text and I don't see why. This style of writing is quite common in novels.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, but 'unlimited wonderfulness' is somewhat awkward. I would like to use what Tang Ho suggests, just change it a bit: 很多美丽的空想， many beautiful moments of daydreaming.